# bug of RapidXML when the value of a xml node is null

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, rapidxml

If the value of node in the xml is null, when we print the xml node, the node has no start tag, but only the end tag. For example:

```
xml_document<char> doc;
doc.append_node(doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_element, "mynode", ""));
ofstream ofs("test.xml");
ofs<<doc;
```

the content of test.xml is:

```
</mynode>
```

the expected content of test.xml is

```
<mynode></mynode>
```

Is this a bug of rapidxml

Comment: So.. what do you want us to do about it?

Comment: Are you sure the content is not `<mynode />` instead ? This has not the same meaning than `</mynode>`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version of RapidXml you're using. I've used few days ago the latest and works fine... this problem was fixed or it was a particular case of yours :)